# Knockoutjs: manually bind specific dynamic iframe in foreach to parent

Tags: iframe, knockout.js

I had a similar question at: [Knockoutjs: bind dynamic iframes in foreach to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507736/knockoutjs-bind-dynamic-iframes-in-foreach-to-parent), that got answered but now I am trying to take this sample a bit further, working with ajax calls and loading async content within one of the iframes...

I am trying to bind dynamically output iframes and parent window so that I can change/update an observable or observable array in either the iframe or parent window and both views will update with new value.

You can see this working for all of the iframes except the first one at http://jsfiddle.net/NnT78/66/

Here is my code

**HTML:**

```
<iframe data-bind="attr: {src: src, 'data-asyncload': async}, bindIframe: $root"></iframe>
```

**KnockoutJS:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bindIframe = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            function bindIframe() {
                try {
                    var iframeInit = element.contentWindow.initChildFrame,
                        iframedoc = element.contentDocument.body;
                } catch (e) {
                    // ignored
                }
                var val = valueAccessor();
                if (iframeInit)
                    iframeInit(ko, valueAccessor());
                else if (iframedoc) {
                    ko.applyBindings(valueAccessor(), iframedoc);
                }
            };

            if($(element).data("asyncload") == false) {
                bindIframe();
                ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'load', bindIframe);
            }
        }
};
```

The first iframe will have an async call that will load the content after the original binding above, that is why I am skipping binding this iframe above with:

```
if($(element).data("asyncload") == false) {
```

To bind the first iframe (after async call is finished and loaded content from data source) I want to call a function that binds that specific iframe with:

```
function bindAsyncOnLoadCallback() {
    $("iframe[data-asyncload='true']").each(function() {
    try {
        var iframeInit = this.contentWindow.initChildFrame,
            iframedoc = this.contentDocument.body;
    } catch (e) {
        // ignored
    }
    if (iframeInit)
        iframeInit(ko, new ViewModel());
    else if (iframedoc) {
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), iframedoc);
    }
});
};
```

The bind in bindAsyncOnLoadCallback() does not seem to be binding to parent window, I think I have got this line wrong??

```
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), iframedoc);
```

You can see working sample of all iframes except the first one binding to parent window at http://jsfiddle.net/NnT78/66/

The reason I want to do this is that I have links in the async content that gets loaded onto the page and need to apply bindings after the ajax content is loaded

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In your last fiddle, the `ViewModel` function is defined inside your IIFE at the bottom and is not accessible to your `bindAsyncOnLoadCallback` function.  After correcting that, then it works when delaying the bind call (the content needs to have been loaded). http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/myq8e/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From the fiddle you posted still seems to not be working? I need the observable array to output and the Click Me link to work (push a new item to the observable array) like the other iframes work

Comment: it seems to work for me (in the second frame) - the one that is marked with `async=true`. the first frame outside of the `foreach` loop would still not work.

Comment: In your fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/myq8e/ when you click 'Click Me' in the async=true frame it should update 'value:' in Outer Document and 'someProperty' in the other iframes just like it is working if you click 'Click Me' in the other iframes

Comment: oh- that is because it is a different ViewModel instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working! Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/myq8e/48/

The problem was that I had to globally declare `ViewModel()` in a variable so I could use it in async callback function:

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
```

**And then use `viewModel` when applying bindings for parent window:**

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**And for async iframes:**

```
function bindAsyncOnLoadCallback() {
    $("iframe[data-asyncload='true']").each(function() {
        try {
            var iframeInit = this.contentWindow.initChildFrame,
                iframedoc = this.contentDocument.body;
        } catch (e) {
            // ignored
        }
        if (iframeInit)
            iframeInit(ko, viewModel);
        else if (iframedoc) {
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel, iframedoc);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Cool trickery.  Always nice to see people doing crazy things with Knockout.  You might want to make sure you're thinking security through properly though as you're exposing that viewModel.

Comment: Oh, and check this out to make your value update more spectacularly :)

http://jsfiddle.net/myq8e/49/

Comment: Thanks @Milimetric! Thanks for the security tip too. I checked out your fiddle to see the spectacular update :) but didn't see anything different??

Comment: The updates to the text box are immediately reflected to the iframes.  Basically, onkeydown as opposed to onblur.